# How to webscrape HTML using PHP dom inside links

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, domdocument

I have a problem regarding HTML webscraping.

```
<div class="mbs fwb">
<a href="/groups/291064327770896/" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/group.php?id=291064327770896" aria-owns="js_0" aria-haspopup="true" aria-describedby="js_1" id="js_2">
NCR Business Startups </a>
</div>

<div class="mbs fwb" >
<a href="/groups/Analystamit/" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/group.php?id=158649140871478" aria-owns="js_0" aria-haspopup="true" aria-describedby="js_1" id="js_2">
Risk Professionals </a>
</div>
```

I need to scrape inside anchor tag `data-hovercard` field.

Below is the code I used:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://sampleurl.com/taki.html');

foreach($html->find('div[class="mbs fwb"]') as $desc11)

foreach($desc11->find('a') as $desc12)

    echo $desc12->data-hovercard . '<br>';
```

It is not working. The result I am getting:

```
0

0
```

I want a result like this:

```
/ajax/hovercard/group.php?id=291064327770896

/ajax/hovercard/group.php?id=158649140871478
```

Comment: /ajax/hovercard/group.php?id=158649140871478

Comment: create a data element then http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: not understood sir, i am learner, can u write full code pls, if u dont mind, thank u..

Comment: `data-hovercard` doesn't seem like a valid object property.

Comment: <div data-collection-item-priv="291064327770896"></div>
<div data-collection-item-priv="158649140871478"></div> how to scrape if we a code like this sir

Comment: i need result should be 291064327770896 and 158649140871478

Answer (score 0):

Use a Regular Expression with a pattern like: /data-hovercard="([^"]*)"/gi;

The resulting matchs' "\1" will contain all of the values for that attribute. You might need to remove newlines from your source text, just for good housekeeping.

Hope this helps.

Comment: how to add regular expression sir? what lines i need to remove

Comment: To remove newlines (newline characters), normally replacing "\n" will do that for you. To learn Regular Expressions, you need to search Google for "Regular Expression" and the language you're using, in this case PHP. Any tutorial will get you where you need to be, if you use the pattern I suggested above. If I just post the code, you've learned nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the built-in [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) class and an [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) query:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('http://foo.bar/baz.html', null, true);
$anchors = $xml->xpath('//div[@class="mbs fwb"]/a');

foreach ($anchors as $a) {
    echo $a['data-hovercard'], PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output, assuming baz.html is a valid HTML file containing the divs
from the question:

```
/ajax/hovercard/group.php?id=291064327770896
/ajax/hovercard/group.php?id=158649140871478
```